# "Nutzen" von Artikeln im Deutschen

Tags: article

Welche Vorteile ergeben sich durch drei Artikel? Würde die Sprache bspw. weniger Möglichkeiten bieten, sich auszudrücken?

Ich habe im Hinterkopf eine große, fürchterliche, fleischfressende Pflanze, aber komme nicht darauf in welchem Zusammenhang ich darüber gelesen habe. (Das war ein Beispiel in einem Text, der sich auf den Nutzen von Artikeln bezieht. Genauer weiß ich es aber nicht mehr.)

In einem anderen Text habe ich von das, die und der Erbe gelesen, mir scheint das aber nur in Ausnahmefällen zuzutreffen.

Das Englische empfinde ich immer etwas "simpel", das kann aber weniger mit dem Wegfall der Artikel, als mit meinem schlechten Englisch zu tun haben.

Comment: Drei Artikel? Also ich zähle da deutlich mehr. (Dieser Kommentar kommt allerdings ohne Artikel aus.)

Comment: @HalvarF Richtig, hätte mich da sauberer ausdrücken können/müssen. :)

Comment: Erwartest du eine Listenantwort?

Comment: @tofro Nein, ich habe mich unpräzise und unsauber ausgedrückt. Ich lasse die Frage mal so stehen. Ich habe gemerkt, dass ich da nochmal nachdenken und mich dann mit einer besseren Frage zurückmelden muss.

Comment: @HalvarF: Du hast recht: *der, die, das, des, dem, den, ein, eine, eines, einem, einen, einer* - Das sind 12 Stück. Zählt man den Nullartikel mit, sogar 13. Die meisten Menschen meinen aber *grammatische Geschlechter* oder *Nominalklassen*, die durch Artikel bezeichnet werden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deiner Frage scheint die Annahme zugrunde zu liegen, dass jemand die heute existierenden Sprachen erfunden oder konstruiert hätte, so wie man einen Staubsauger oder ein Auto konstruiert. Denn da hat es Sinn danach zu fragen, warum der Einschaltknopf des Staubsaugers nicht beim Griff sondern beim Motor ist, oder warum das Autoradio nicht in der Mittelkonsole ist, sondern in der Fahrertür.

Aber Sprachen wurden nicht von Einzelpersonen oder kleinen Gruppen in einem durchgeplanten Entwicklungsprojekt erfunden. Sie haben sich über Jahrhunderte und Jahrtausende hinweg aus Vorgängersprachen entwickelt.

Wir wissen nicht, was die Vorgängersprache der Indogermanischen Ursprache war, und selbst das, was wir über die Indogermanischen Ursprache wissen, ist "nur" rekonstruiertes Wissen, weil schon seit Jahrtausenden niemand mehr diese Sprache spricht, und weil sie damals niemand aufgeschrieben hat.

Aus den heute lebenden Sprachen und aus den Schriftfunden früherer Zeiten lässt sich aber mit großer Sicherheit sagen, dass die Sprecher der Indogermanischen Ursprache zwischen Lebewesen (Menschen, Tiere, Götter, Dämonen usw.) und unbelebten Gegenständen (Steine, Pflanzen, Erde, Wasser, usw.) unterschieden haben, wobei diese Einteilung nicht ganz damit übereinstimmt, wie wir heute "lebend" und "nicht lebend" definieren würden. Es ging damals eher darum, ob sich ein Ding von selbst bewegen kann oder nicht.

Für die lebenden Dinge hat sich damals unter den Sprechern dieser Ursprache eingebürgert, einen anderen Artikel zu verwenden als für die unbelebten. Aus dem Artikel für die lebenden Dinge ist dann im Lauf der Jahrtausende in den Nachfolgesprachen der Artikel geworden, den wir heute *»männlich«* nennen. (Im Deutschen: *»der«*.) Und aus dem Artikel für die unbelebten Dinge wurde der sächliche Artikel. (Deutsch: *»das«*.)

Darüber hinaus unterschieden die Menschen damals zwischen einem Ding, zwei Dingen (Paaren) und vielen Dingen. Das haben sie auch in der Sprache zum Ausdruck gebracht. Daher gab es schon damals, in der Indoeuropäischen Ursprache den Singular, den Dual und den Plural, jeweils auch mit eigenen Artikeln. Der Dual starb dann im Lauf der Zeit in fast allen Nachfolgesprachen aus, davon haben sich nur in einigen Dialekte (z.B. Bayrisch) Reste erhalten, aber die Unterscheidung zwischen Singular und Plural hielt man wohl in allen Nachfolgesprachen für nützlich, daher existieren auch in allen Nachfolgesprachen diese beiden Zahl-Klassen, wobei zum Plural in vielen Sprachen auch ein eigener Artikel gehört. (Im Deutschen: *»die«*.)

Diese Plural-Klasse hat man dann aber irgendwann auch verwendet, um bei den lebenden Dingen weiter zu differenzieren. Man unterschied bei lebenden Dingen zwischen männlich und weiblich, und verwendete bei den männlichen Lebewesen den alten Artikel für lebende Dinge weiter, und ging bei den Weiblichen dazu über, sie sprachlich zu behandeln, als wären es viele, wodurch sich aus der Plural-Klasse die Klasse der weiblichen Nomen weiterentwickelt hat.

Nachdem sich diese Unterteilungen bereits etabliert hatten, entwickelte sich die Indoeuropäische Sprachenfamilie aber weiter.

In Zentraleuropa wurden gesprochen: Langobardisch, Altalemannisch, Altbayrisch, Altfränkisch, Sächsisch, Gotisch, Vanadisch, Friesisch und viele andere Sprachen, die man in einem gewissen Sinn als Dialekte einer Urgermanischen Sprache ansehen kann. Diese Sprachengruppe ist der Gemeinsame Vorfahr von Deutsch, Englisch, Niederländisch, Dänisch, Schwedisch, Afrikaans, Jiddisch und Scots, wobei die heute existierenden germanischen Sprachen zu unterschiedlichen Anteilen auf den Urgermanischen Sprachen beruhen.

Aber vor 1500 Jahren waren die Vorgänger von Englisch und Deutsch noch dieselben Sprachen, und diese Vorgängersprachen hatten noch alle drei Geschlechter im Singular. Nachdem sich Englisch auf den britischen Inseln geographisch vom kontinentaleuropäischen Deutsch getrennt hatte, entwickelten sich die beiden Sprachen unterschiedlich, und Englisch verlor viele Features, die in anderen germanischen Sprachen erhalten blieben.

In der modernen englischen Sprache erinnern nur mehr acht Wörter an das große Gebäude der Nominalklassen: *he, him, his, she, her, hers, it, its.* Von diesen acht Wörtern abgesehen gibt es im Englischen keine Unterscheidung mehr zwischen den grammatischen Geschlechtern, insbesondere haben im Englischen alle Nomen ihr Geschlecht verloren, während im Deutschen jedes Nomen (mindestens) ein Geschlecht hat.

---

Die Frage, welche Vorteile unterschiedliche Artikel haben, ist also falsch gestellt. Man könnte vielleicht fragen, warum dieses System auf dem Kontinent erhalten geblieben ist, und warum es auf den britischen Inseln verschwunden ist. Aber die Antwort darauf ist vermutlich ganz einfach nur Zufall. Ebenso könnte man fragen, warum die Schnäbel der Finken auf den Galapagosinseln diese spezielle Form haben, während die nächsten Verwandten dieser Vögel auf einem Kontinent eine andere Form haben. Das ist nur eine Folge des Einflusses des Zufalls auf die Evolution. Und lebende Sprachen unterliegen ebenso der Evolution wie Tier- und Pflanzengattungen.

Es hat ja auch keinen Sinn danach zu fragen, welchen Vorteil es hat, dass der [Nervus laryngeus recurrens](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nervus_laryngeus_recurrens), der bei uns Menschen (und bei allen Säugetieren, Vögeln und Reptilien) das Gehirn mit dem Kehlkopf verbindet, beim Herzen vorbei laufen muss. (Bei Giraffen ist das ein Umweg von 5 Metern.) Es hat auch keinen Sinn zu fragen, welchen Vorteil es hat, dass bei Männern der Samenleiter, der die Hoden mit dem Penis verbindet, unbedingt bis zur Blase aufsteigen muss wenn es doch einen kürzeren Weg gäbe. Oder welchen Vorteil es hat, dass die lichtempfindlichen Zellen in unseren Augen auf der Außenseite der Augenwand liegen, statt dort, wo das Licht hinfällt, also innen. Welchen Vorteil hat es, das die weiblichen Vertreter der Menschen, aller Menschenaffen und einiger Fledermausarten während ihrer fruchtbaren Lebensspanne regelmäßig bluten, während die Fortpflanzung bei allen anderen Säugetieren ohne Blutverlust funktioniert? Warum haben die männlichen Vertreter der Menschen Hoden, die so wärmeempfindlich sind, dass sie in einem Sack außerhalb des Körpers herumbaumeln müssen, während Elefanten, die auch eine Körpertemperatur von 37 Grad haben, kein Problem damit haben, ihre Hoden gut geschützt im Inneren des Körpers aufzubewahren? Nichts davon hat irgend einen Vorteil, aber es ist eben durch die Evolution so entstanden.

Und so ist das auch bei vielen Features von Sprachen. Suaheli hat nicht nur 3 Geschlechter/Nominalklassen, sondern mehr als 20. Ungarisch hat über 30 grammatische Fälle. Englisch hat 16 Zeitformen während Deutsch mit 6 auskommt und Japanisch gar keine hat. Nichts davon kann man mit Vor- oder Nachteilen begründen.

Comment: Ich hatte das so verstanden dass der Verlust der Artikel im englischen daher kam dass die Sprache über die Normannen vom französischen beeinflusst wurde und das grammatikalische Geschlecht im (alt-/mittel-englischen) und französischen sich oft unterschied. Die einfachste Lösung war es, die Artikel wegzulassen.

Comment: Nein, die Vorstellung einer Konstruktion hatte ich nicht. Den Reflex, Fragen in der Richtung so zu verstehen, habe ich noch nie richtig durchdrungen. Vielen Dank, dass du meine unpräzise und schlecht gestellte Frage trotzdem zu beantworten versucht hast.

Answer (score 1):

Gäbe es nur einen Artikel, wäre das Klangbild insgesamt monotoner. Mehrere Artikel zu haben, ist daher ein stilistischer Vorteil ([variatio delectat](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/variatio_delectat)).